# how to increase stack of popPage() in OnsenUI?

Tags: cordova, stack, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

currently I am developing application in phonegap through OpenUI framework. I  want to **increase the stack of the popPage()** function. Currently i can go back previous page, but not more than that. Can i give **ons.navigator.pushPage()** transition same as **popPage()**? Please someone help me to solve these issue as soon as possible.

Comment: you can only pop as many times as you pushed. may be you want to pushPage but with different animation?

Comment: what i mean is there are 3 pages index.html, first.html and second.html. if we start from index, push to first.html and then push to second.html, now what happens is that when i popPage from second it only goes to first, it doesn't go back from first to index. Please help me to solve these issue m facing..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to jump to the first page skipping the first.html.

You can use **ons.navigator.resetToPage(url)**

Let's say you have index.html, page1.html, page2.html, and page3.html.
When we are in page3.html, we want to jump to page1.html, skipping page2.html.

**index.html**

index.html has page1.html as the root page.

```
<body>
  <ons-navigator page="page1.html"></ons-navigator>
</body>
```

**page1.html**

page1 will push to page 2

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-button ng-click="ons.navigator.pushPage('page2.html')">
     Push Page 2
  </ons-button>
</ons-page>
```

**page2.html**

page 2 will push to page 3

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-button ng-click="ons.navigator.pushPage('page3.html')">
     Push Page 3
  </ons-button>
</ons-page>
```

**page3.html**

page 3 will reset to page 1 (skipping page 2)

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-button ng-click="ons.navigator.resetToPage('page1.html')">
     Reset to page 1
  </ons-button>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: suppose from page3.html i perform popPage() which goes to page2.html, but when from  page2.html i perform popPage() it doesn't go to page1.html. I tried resetToPage, but it doesn't give any transition effect. it seems that popPage only goes to 1 previous page.

Comment: i don't want to skip any pages while performing popPage()

Answer (score 1):

i am facing the same way as your problems.
I'm end up with overriding default popPage function.

Here what i'm trying to do.

```
ons.ready(function(){
    /* Custom poppage */
    ons.navigator._popPage = function(options){
        var unlock = this._doorLock.lock();

        var leavePage = this.pages.pop();

        var step = options.step ? options.step : 1; // added step option

        if (this.pages[this.pages.length - step]) {
          this.pages[this.pages.length - step].element.css('display', 'block');
        }

        var enterPage = this.pages[this.pages.length -step];

        var event = {
          leavePage: leavePage,
          enterPage: this.pages[this.pages.length - step],
          navigator: this
        };

        var callback = function() {
            for(var s=1; s < step; s++){
                this.pages[this.pages.length - s].destroy();   // also destroy skipped page                    
            }
            leavePage.destroy();
            unlock();
            this.emit('postpop', event);
            event.leavePage = null;

            if (typeof options.onTransitionEnd === 'function') {
            options.onTransitionEnd();
            }
        }.bind(this);

        leavePage.options.animator.pop(enterPage, leavePage, callback);
    }
});
```

i add step variable in the options params to let me decide how many page that i want to going back.

Here how i use my custom function :

```
ons.navigator.popPage({step:2});
```

not very clever solution maybe, but i hope it can point you for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use ons.navigator.resetToPage(url) too, and you can set animation with the second param for options, example:

`ons.navigator.resetToPage(url, { animation: 'fade' })`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/226

You can destroy the pages in the middle, then pop the state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about **onsen ui ver.2**, but using **onsen ui ver.1**, you can define a var attribute in **ons-navigator tag** like this:

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="testing_Nav">
  . 
  .
  .
  .
</ons-navigator>
```

and in your js file, you can navigate to your desired page using that variable like this:

```
testing_Nav.resetToPage('page_name.html', {animation: 'fade'});
```

For More Information: 
[Onsen UI Documentation](https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-navigator.html)